# Protonmail login does´t work any more with TOR Browser 7.0 and later

Tags: email

https://protonmail.com/login
or
https://protonirockerxow.onion/

Alfter loggin in with username and password skript seems to stuck -> nothing goes -> no login

With TOR Browser 6.5.2 it worked.

Deactivating https everywhere and noscript doesn´t change this error.

Comment: been using protonmail with tor and have not seen or suffered from this issue. what are your security settings? https everywhere shouldnt effect this but using no script to allow javascript to run which is required for proton login.
have you tried contacting protonmail about it?
are you using a fast enough circuit? perhaps your timing out. ultimately without either more info and/or contacting protonmail to see if anything is odd on their end, i dont know what could be done.

Comment: Ive been having problems as well. When I try to login, it will show the protonmail loading icon until you close the page.

Answer (score 1):

The comments on this blog announcement describe the problem, it's root cause and how to work around it.  https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-701-released
In short, the ProtonMail login is using JavaScript Just-in-Time compilation which Tor Browser 7.0.1 doesn't allow except in the "Low" security setting.  After setting the security slider down to "Low", it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fly Boy,

Your answer is right. In TOR Browser 6.5.2 I had security settings on middle, in 7.0.1 you have to set security settings on low to run protonmail.
In 7.0.1 security behavier of TOR Browser is different than in 6.5.2.
In 6.5.2 Protonmail was also running with security setting "middle".